# background colour for overflow after min height for inner div

Tags: html, css

I've a background image for body and a background color for wrapper div.
I haven't set any height for body and I'm using a min-height:1000px for wrapper.
But if wrapper height extends 1000px;, the background color of wrapper is as body background image.
HTML Code:

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headercontainer">
      <div id="company"></div>
      <div id="tagline"></div>
      <div id="navigation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagecontainer1"></div>
  <div id="footer1"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
body{
background:#E8EDF0;
    margin:0;
width:100%;
background-image: url(http://l1.yimg.com/a/i/ww/met/th/slate/gsprite_pg_slate_20100521.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: 0px -2335px;}
#wrapper{
background-color:#FFF;
min-height:1000px;
width:1008px;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
overflow:visible;
}
```

How can i fix this background color issue for wrapper.

Comment: Some html as well would be nice :)

Comment: I cant see anything like that in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8Bdpz/10/).  It is showing the background-color of wrapper itself ?

Comment: maybe thn it's problem in my rest of code, here is the link www.agbcorplegal.com/test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the way you coded your page, you can't get the wrapper to cover the full height. So the best way to do it is to make a background image for your full body like this:

#### grey area##-----white area: 1008px-----###grey area

make it 2000px wide (or more), 1px high, and repeat vertically:

```
background:#E8EDF0 url(new-background-path.jpg) top center repeat-y;
```

Comment: @umesh maybe there's an error in your code, so that the #wrapper is being closed before the end of the contents... I've reproduced it "on scale" here: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/tScyJ/ , as you can see the wrapper is extending well over the `min-height:10px;`

Comment: You're missing the `</body>` and `</html>` closing tags! Try to add them, at the end of your document

Comment: @umesh the problem is with the divs positioned in absolute mode... you've to review your full code, or check my edit

Comment: @umesh i'm not sure, give it a try. But i think the best solution for your case is to add the white-central area directly in the body background

Answer (score 0):

simply add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` in pagecontainer1 div. coz i think there are some float div so to clear float use float clear or you can use overflow:hidden; rather than overflow:visible;

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headercontainer">
      <div id="company"></div>
      <div id="tagline"></div>
      <div id="navigation"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pagecontainer1">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer1"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding the new div after pagecontainer1 and footer still overflow:hidden doesn't works for me.

Comment: i have checked your test page in wrapper div there are inner divs which are using position absolute so height of wrapper div is not increasing as no of content increasing.so you should update your page structure first.or instent solution is increase min-height of wrapper div.

Comment: position absolute is used for many div,hence updating structure is tedious, even min-height inc. not possible, isn't there any other alternative by making smaller changes??